# How can I know which instance i am working with, inside a method of an abstract class?

Tags: java, instance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and i am wondering if it is possible to know the instance of that class inside one of its methods.

I mean if there's any way to get it. Like some java method like `myClass.whereAmI()` or something like that.

For example:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    public void myMethod(String string){

        String instance = MyClass.getClass(); //I want to get the type of the instance.
        ....

    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried this.getClass() ?

Comment: Yes, you can, however any design which relies on this behaviour is usually bad.

Comment: The point is: a *base* class should **not at all** know about specific sub classes. By asking "what subclass is running this method" you basically make the base dependent on the child class, and that is *always* wrong.

Comment: Okay i understand, you are right, i think i am gonna get that instance before i call the method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `getClass()` instance method inherited from `java.lang.Object`:

```
public void myMethod(String string) {
    Class<?> instanceClass = getClass();
    String instanceClassName = instanceClass.getName();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job, but i am going to avoid doing this cause of the comment of @GhostCat. Thank you very much!